# how come list.containsAll(emptylist) returns true?

Tags: java

How is it possible that when I have a List that contains elements, and I call the containsAll method on this list with an empty list as an argument, it returns true? The empty list doesen't contain any elements so how can both lists have any elements in common?

Comment: In mathematics, the empty set is a subset of any set "A". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Javadoc of `List`:

> **boolean java.util.List.containsAll(Collection c)**
>
> Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

If `c` contains no elements, the list on which you call the method does contain all the elements of `c`, which is why `true` is returned.

Comment: but c contains no elements. How can the list that you call the method on contain any elements of a list that contains no elements at all? I still don't understand.

Comment: @Maurice Well, there is no element of `c` which is not contained in the list you call the method on. Hence, that list can be said to contain all the elements of `c` (even if there are no such elements).

Comment: Maybe the semantics make more sense with an example about applying for a job. Say you have a set of skills `mySkills`, and the job requires certain skills, `requiredSkills`. You could test if you can apply for the job by checking `mySkills.containsAll(requiredSkills)`. Now, if there would be a really easy job, `requiredSkills` would be empty. Does that automatically make you fit for the job? Absolutely! So `mySkills.containsAll(emptySet())` should also return `true`.